# How can I gathering Network Traffic on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables, packet-capture, tee

I am building packet mirroring using the Linux type's iptables tee module. In the case of instances(EC2), we confirmed that promiscuous mode can be set on AWS console configuration. than, I wonder if it's possible to use promiscuous mode  on ELB(ALB,NLB), not instance(EC2). Related design plans are as follows.

```
     (communicate)        (duplicate)
```

** A(EC2) ====> B (ELB)   -------------> C (ELB(NLB/ALB) / litsening )

Ps. Or, Do you have any good idea when we capture real-time Network traffic ?

Answer (score 1):

Promiscuous mode doesn't work in AWS, and you can't do anything like that with an ELB. If you had a load balancer you set up using HAProxy or similar maybe you could do it in software.

[VPC flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) let you capture information about each flow in a VPC, but it's not packet capture.

[VPC Traffic Mirroring](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-traffic-mirroring/) might do what you want.

> You can think of VPC Traffic Mirroring as a “virtual fiber tap” that
>   gives you direct access to the network packets flowing through your
>   VPC. As you will soon see, you can choose to capture all traffic or
>   you can use filters to capture the packets that are of particular
>   interest to you, with an option to limit the number of bytes captured
>   per packet. You can use VPC Traffic Mirroring in a multi-account AWS
>   environment, capturing traffic from VPCs spread across many AWS
>   accounts and then routing it to a central VPC for inspection.